# Is Cell.AccessoryType = .none or .checkmark is Sufficient to make a cell checked or unchecked or should i include this extra line

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift4

[image]

Please click above to see the Image and Pls answer this

should i include that todo.array.checked = !ofthe same 
or that above Accessory method is sufficient to make the cell checked or unchecked.
Btw - todo is the name of the class in which i'm storing all my data and everything is present inside an array with two properties 
1) Data and 2) check

Comment: Please post code (text), not images

Comment: where do you call the `configureData`? Please edit your question and post the code as text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO. Don't post pictures of code. Paste the code into your question and mark it with code tags.

You should not just set the checked state on the cell. Cells get recycled, and if you scroll an entry in your table view off-screen and scroll it back, you'll lose the selected state of the cell.

You should indeed record the selected state into your data model like the code you posted, and then in your `cellForRow(at:)` method you should use the flag from your data model to set the checked/unchecked state of the cell you are configuring.

Comment: So you mean that todo.array[indexpath.row].checked is storing the value( Checkmark Value) so that those value can be restored when i start the app again or if i scroll up or down

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.